FinishTransaction not working while paying for Android in-app on apps made with RN Webview
I get an error when doing finishTransaction after the Android in-app payment process in an app I made with RN Webview. I'm using the react-native-iap library.
const purchase = async (sku: string, itemId: string, accessToken: string) => {
    console.info('Purchase start');
    console.info(JSON.stringify({sku, itemId, accessToken}, null, 2));

    let order: any;
    try {
      const {data} = await axios.post(
        `${Config.WEBVIEW_HOST}api/purchase/prepare`,
        {
          packId: itemId,
          price: sku.split('_').pop(),
          amount: 1,
          currency: 'KRW',
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        },
      );
      console.info('Purchase prepared');
      console.info(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      if (data.message !== 'success') {
        Alert.alert('Error', data.message);
        return;
      }
      order = data;
      console.info('order', order);
      await getProducts({skus: typeof sku === 'object' ? sku : [sku]});
      const requestParams: any = {};

      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        requestParams.skus = typeof sku === 'object' ? sku : [sku];
      } else {
        requestParams.sku = sku;
        requestParams.andDangerouslyFinishTransactionAutomaticallyIOS = false;
      }
      const purchases = await requestPurchase(requestParams);
      const {data: webhookResponse} = await axios.post(
        `${Config.WEBVIEW_HOST}api/purchase/webhook`,
        {
          imp_uid: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'Apple' : 'Android',
          merchant_uid: order.result.id,
          receipt: (purchases as any).transactionReceipt,
          status: 'paid',
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        },
      );
      console.info('Webhook response');
      console.info(JSON.stringify(webhookResponse, null, 2));
      if (webhookResponse.message !== 'success') {
        Alert.alert('Error', webhookResponse.message);
        return;
      }

      if (purchases) {
        if (Array.isArray(purchases)) {
          for (const _purchase of purchases) {
            await finishTransaction({
              purchase: _purchase,
              isConsumable: true,
              ...(Platform.OS === 'android'
                ? {developerPayloadAndroid: ''}
                : {}),
            });
          }
        } else {
          await finishTransaction({
            purchase: purchases,
            isConsumable: true,
            ...(Platform.OS === 'android' ? {developerPayloadAndroid: ''} : {}),
          });
        }
      }

      webViewRef.current?.injectJavaScript(
        `try {
          window.finishPurchase({
            itemId: '${itemId}',
            orderId: '${order.result.id}'
          });
        } catch(error) {
          console.warn(error);
        }`,
      );
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.warn(err.code, err.message);
      await axios.post(
        `${Config.WEBVIEW_HOST}api/purchase/cancel`,
        {
          orderId: order.result.id,
        },
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
          },
        },
      );
      Alert.alert('Cancel', `${err.code} ${err.message}`);
    }
  };

For this, when I ran the finishTransaction function, I only had Android branching out separately. But it seems like it's falling into the catch door because there's an error in that line. That's why I think I'm sending cancel after payment.
 if (purchases) {
        if (Array.isArray(purchases)) {
          for (const _purchase of purchases) {
            await finishTransaction({
              purchase: _purchase,
              isConsumable: true,
              ...(Platform.OS === 'android'
                ? {developerPayloadAndroid: ''}
                : {}),
            });
          }
        } else {
          await finishTransaction({
            purchase: purchases,
            isConsumable: true,
            ...(Platform.OS === 'android' ? {developerPayloadAndroid: ''} : {}),
          });
        }
      }

